# Why did Harmonica tear off Jill's clothes?

Tags: once-upon-a-time-in-the-west

A question regarding *Once Upon a Time in the West*. When Harmonica first met Jill in McBain's farm he tore off her clothes and his behavior looks very unpredictable.

Was the purpose that he did not want Jill to leave the farm?

Comment: I'll have to rewatch this after work today, but from my spotty recollection, I believe you are confusing scenes. Frank was the one who raped Jill, not Harmonica. Like I said, I'll rewatch it tonight.

Comment: I know that it was Frank who raped Jill. Harmonica did only tear her clothes. There was no sexual assault in his act.

Answer (score 5):

Harmonica knew Frank's men would be observing from afar for the right moment to launch an assault.
Tearing her clothes apart, sending her out, following her and then taking parts of his clothes off is to show vulnerability.

Frank's men were clearly surprised to see a man coming out of the farm, they had no idea who he was hence were cautious at first. The scene harmonica set up clearly worked as it lowered their guards getting g then to rush in.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down-voted. This was my take on the scene as well.